# Divide and Conquer Method in "R. Sedgewick Algorithms in Java: Parts 1-4"

Tags: java, algorithm, search

In chapter 5 of the book in the title, there is description of "divide and conquer" method for finding max number in array with following image attached:

[image]

Java code used:

```
static double max(double a[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l == r) return a[l];
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    double u = max(a, l, m);
    double v = max(a, m+1, r);
    if (u > v) return u; else return v;
}
```

I think the picture is incorrect. For example, method call with (0, 1) i.e. T max(0,1) should return I not T.
Am I right ?

Also here is mistake in further picture in the book:

[image: three tree models]

Please clarify maybe something wrong with my understanding of recursion.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised why he's using an inclusive upper bound - while it doesn't matter too much in this example in general it's more complicated I think (well maybe I've just gotten used to this convention). Anyways you've got a bug in your code: `(l+r)/2` is influenced by overflows, so you should always use `l + (r - l) / 2` instead.

Comment: Please use the image-button to include images in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The example shown in your first picture is returning the highest letter, not number, in the array.  The numbers shown are there to indicate the array index of each letter.  Because T > I, `max(0,1)` returns T.  The overall return value of the algorithm is Y because it is the highest letter out of all of them.

In your second picture, the each node of the first tree appears to be the sum of its immediate children nodes; each node of the second tree appears to be the floor of the average of its immediate children nodes; and the third tree basically shows what your first picture showed.

I hope this clarifies things for you!

Answer (score 0):

First: The code uses `double`, the example seems to used `char`, so the example and the code are not perfectly aligned.

Second: In `max(l, r)` the `l` and `r` are indizes into the array, not the actual values. The compared values are `T` and `I`. On my ASCII table and my alphabet `I` comes before `T`, so `I` is considerd smaller than `T`. So the maximum of both is `T`.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the picture is incorrect. For example, method call with (0, 1) i.e. T max(0,1) should return I not T. Am I right ?

No.

A call to `max(a, 0, 1)` assigns `m = 0`, and then recursively calls `max(a, 0, 0)` and `max(a, 1, 1)`.  The values `u` and `v` are `'T'` and `'I'` respectively, and the largest of these is `'T'` ... which is returned.

Comment: Ok, guess I got it). The main misunderstanding for me was that the type of the array was double so I thought the indexes and array values were the same and the letters just for visualization.

Thanks everyone for answering.